# Deploying spring-beans 3.0.7 overrides somehow xml factory classes which are slower than the default

Tags: java, spring, jboss, jboss6.x

We are currently implementing cxf services (separate WAR) into a legacy system (EAR file) on JBoss 5 eap.
But if we deploy spring-beans.3.0.7 (needed by cxf) on the WAR, it provides different xml factory classes which are slower, so that we have no performance issues.

Is it possible to prevent spring from populating different factory classes?
Or would it be possible to get all factory classes provided by spring, so that we can overrid them back?

I'm not able to find out which spring lib is causing this behaviour.